# Trying to pass MediaMetadataRetriever to a class to make MainActivity less clutered, but methods return null

Tags: java, android

`I've made this MusicData class to replace a method in main activity passing the path for a music file in the storage and an initialized MediaMetaDataRetriever from MainActivity.

```
public class MusicData {
    String path;
    String artist;
    String title;
    String album;

    public String getTitle(String path, MediaMetadataRetriever metadataRetriever){
        metadataRetriever.setDataSource(path);
        try{
            title = metadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
            return title;
        }catch(Exception e){
            title = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")).replace("/","");
            return title;
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(String path){
        metadataRetriever.setDataSource(path);
        try{
            byte [] data = metadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            metadataRetriever.release();
            return bitmap;
        }catch(Exception e){

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I think I need to pass the context from MainActivity so the class could retrieve the data from storage, but I have yet to figure out how utilize that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I would take a different approach, instead of sending the file path I send the File data itself and create a MediaMetadataRetriever inside of the class.

```
public String getTitle(File file){
    path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    MediaMetadataRetriever mr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mr.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
    try{
        title = mr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
        mr.release();
        return title;
    }catch(Exception e){
        mr.release();
        title = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")).replace("/","");
        return title;
    }
}
```